# Why isn't Rust able to optimise a match on a specific error as well as it does for is_err()?

Tags: optimization, rust

Consider this code:

```
enum MyError {
    BadError, NotSoBad,
}

#[inline(never)]
fn do_stuff1<T>(m: Result<T, MyError>) -> bool {
    m.is_err()
}

#[inline(never)]
fn do_stuff2<T>(m: Result<T, MyError>) -> bool {
    if let Err(MyError::BadError) = m {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

The resulting assembly (see [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=0537efb6aff12caf563d0150a02f61cc)):

```
playground::do_stuff1:
    cmpb    $1, %dil
    sete    %al
    retq

playground::do_stuff2:
    testb   %dil, %dil
    setne   %cl
    testb   %sil, %sil
    sete    %al
    andb    %cl, %al
    retq
```

Testing `result.is_err()` results in just one byte comparison, which seems reasonable but pattern-matching for the specific error results in a few more instructions.

This is because the error type is actually encoded as a separate byte from the error flag. A `Result<u64, MyError>` is laid out like this:

```
    .--- is error?
   /
  /  .--- error variant 
 /  /
01 01 XX XX XX XX XX XX 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
      \               / \                     /
       `-- padding --'   `---- data (u64) ---'
```

My expectation was that a single byte would be used to encode both the fact that there is an error and which variant the error is, which would allow for simpler assembly.

Is there a reason why this optimisation isn't possible, or are there some tradeoffs that would make it undesirable?

Comment: Honestly, I honestly think it's just oversight/a lot of work to implement correctly. Rust recently got `NonNull` (and `NonZero`) to minimize the storage required to optimize `Optional` so it's as efficient as a raw pointer. Unlike Optional, this only works for certain data types (NonNull or unsaturated enumerations), so it likely hasn't been a priority yet. (This is a guess, but...).

Comment: It's just not clever enough (yet). Currently the [code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/librustc/ty/layout.rs#L921) basically falls back to normal tagged union layout whenever more than one `enum` variant is non-zero-sized, even if one of them has a niche that could replace the tag. `Result<u64, MyError>` has two dataful variants, so the compiler just gives up.

Comment: If you were to use `Result<Result<u64, NotSoBad>, BadError>` you would find the compiler happy to optimize it -- it handles nesting just fine. I tried to demonstrate this in the playground but was stymied by the optimizer deleting and deduplicating most of my code, even with `inline(never)`.